# Why won't my aggregates group?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So I have this code and it doesn't work:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1
SELECT 
  WeekNumber-1 AS [WeekNumber],
  EmplName,
  ROUND(SUM(ManHrs), 2) AS [ManHrs],
  ROUND((SUM(ManHrs) OVER(PARTITION BY EmplName)/((CONVERT(FLOAT, GETDATE())-
  CONVERT(FLOAT, DATEADD(dd,
  ((DATEDIFF(dd,'17530101',GETDATE())/7)*7)-29,'17530101')))/7)), 2) AS [Avg 
  Weekly Man Hrs]
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
  DATEPART(wk, TicketDate) AS WeekNumber,
  e.EmplName,
  t.WorkCntr,
  t.ManHrs
  FROM TimeTicketDet t JOIN EmplCode e ON t.EmplCode = e.Emplcode
  WHERE CONVERT(DATE, TicketDate) > DATEADD(dd,
((DATEDIFF(dd,'17530101',GETDATE())/7)*7)-29,'17530101')
) AS [Subquery]
GROUP BY WeekNumber, EmplName
ORDER BY 2, 1
```

The error says "Column 'Subquery.ManHrs' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"

So when I add ManHrs to the GROUP BY clause, the code runs, but nothing is grouped.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong

Here's a screenshot of the code running by adding the ManHrs to the GROUP BY clause, if it's easier to read:

[image]

**EDIT: Okay, so I figured it out with the help of Rominus, here's the code working as intended:**

[image]

Comment: Add your aggregation to your grouping

Comment: If I do that I get all the records as you can see in the screenshot.  Each employee should only have 5 records, for weeks 28-32

Comment: No I mean literally add the aggregate expression to the group by instead of just the column. If that won't get the results, group in the subquery perhaps? Also, you are probably killing performance with that CONVERT and DATEDIFF in the WHERE clause. If you can avoid that, I would recommend it.

Comment: It says windowed functions are disallowed in the group by clause, maybe I'm just an idiot and you're referring to something else.  And that was the best way I could come with with the last 4 weeks  starting with the Monday 4 weeks ago, so that's the reason for that DATEFIFF.  I'm sure there's a better way, but not really a big concern atm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `GROUP BY` isn't working because it's looking at the different values of ManHrs when grouping, so it considers rows with different ManHrs values to be in different groups.  What you need to do is to sum the ManHrs by week before you group for the averaging.  So you'd end up with two layers of subquery, which would look something like this simplified example:

```
SELECT a.EmplName, a.WeekNumber, SUM(a.Manhrs) as totHrs
FROM
    (SELECT 
    DATEPART(wk, TicketDate) AS WeekNumber
    , e.EmplName
    , t.ManHrs
    FROM TimeTicketDet t JOIN EmplCode e ON t.EmplCode =  e.Emplcode) as a
group by a.EmplName, a.WeekNumber
```

Once you have this kind of subquery you can do your averaging and such in the outer query.

Comment: Figured it out with your help, posted final code in my question, thanks